# What city is this cityscape?

Tags: identify-this, cities, hong-kong

I download this cityscape from Microsoft theme [website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/cityscapes-panoramic-download-theme) but I don't know what city is it.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a panoramic view of [Hong Kong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong). Thanks to [Google Images Search](https://www.google.com.sa/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know google image search tool ^^ Cool!

Comment: To be exact, it's a view from the Peak towards the north-east during sunrise.